How to handle only base url in universal links in iOS?
I am struggled with handling universal links in iOS. How can I handle only base url eg. "www.google.com", "www.google.com/?params...", but not "www.google.com/path..."?
I have tried to define apple-app-site-association multiple times, but nothing worked.
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": ["TEAM_ID.IDENTIFIER"],
                "paths": [
                   "/",
                   "/?*"
                 ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

What worked for base url was:
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": ["TEAM_ID.IDENTIFIER"],
                "paths": [
                   "/"
                 ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

But it didn't work for parameters...
Thanks for help

? is the query, not the path.
